# Checking count of bytes read by istream::read()

Tags: c++, istream

Is there posibility (any method) to check count of bytes read by function presented below:

```
istream& read (char* s, streamsize n);
```

Comment: I recommend you check an [`std::istream` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream). I'm sure you'll find a fitting function to return the *count* of the number of bytes read.

Comment: -1: Spend thirty seconds reading the documentation for the language features that you use.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
std::streamsize gcount() const;
```

Returns the number of characters extracted by the last unformatted input operation.

[gcount](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/gcount)

Comment: Probably not thread-safe?

Answer (score 1):

you can use [gcount](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/gcount)

```
stream.read(x, sizeof x)
stream.gcount();
```

Comment: Is this just a ripoff of the above answer? You even have the same link. -1